# Add external network to openstack

Tags: networking, openstack

I am using OpenStack Packstack Train. I installed it on my server but I have external servers in my lab that I want to reach from the VMs that are on OpenStack. These VM have already a floating IPs.

I want to know if there is like a virtual switch to link them to the external servers or something like that.

When I run `brctl show`, I get

```
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
```

When I do an `ip a`, I see

```
br-ex: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000 
link/ether 32:6c:e3:45:a2:41 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff 
inet 172.24.4.1/24 scope global br-ex valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 
inet6 fe80::306c:e3ff:fe45:a241/64 scope link valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

but when I do `cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scropts/ifcfg-br-ex`, I'm getting this message:
`cat: ifcfg-br-ex: No such file or directory`.

Comment: when i do an ip a i see :  br-ex: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 32:6c:e3:45:a2:41 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.24.4.1/24 scope global br-ex
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::306c:e3ff:fe45:a241/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever                                                                                   but when i do : /etc/sysconfig/network-scropts/ifcfg-br-ex,i'm getting this message : cat: ifcfg-br-ex: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

By default, Packstack creates an "external" network that is not external at all. It is isolated on the Packstack server. You can see that from `br-ex`'s IP address 172.24.4.1, and from the floating IPs of your VMs.

Luckily, the RDO project has [instructions](https://www.rdoproject.org/networking/neutron-with-existing-external-network/) for connecting your cloud to your network.

It might also be possible to add a provider network to the current cloud, but you would have to reconfigure your bridging and Neutron manually, and judging from the question, this is probably beyond your skills (personally, I would have to experiment even after working with OpenStack for seven years). I suggest you just reinstall.

If your VMs contain important data, you could create snapshots, copy them to a safe place, and use them to launch the VMs on the newly deployed cloud.

By the way, `brctl` reports nothing because it only works with Linuxbridges, not Openvswitch bridges (and `br-ex` is the latter). There is no `ifcfg` file because Packstack doesn't bother persisting `br-ex`'s configuration, which will cause you grief when you reboot the Packstack server.